# Pandas DataFrame is empty when it shouldn't

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to merge two dataframes in python with pandas with this line of code:

`merger = pd.merge(COMMODITY, df_new, left_index=True, right_index=True)`

But when printing out the table it's still empty. Why is that?

Columns COMMODITY: ['date', 'vaule', 'date_id']

```
           date        value   date_id
date                                     
2023-04-04 2023-04-04  1523.50 2023-04-04
2023-04-04 2023-04-04  1521.25 2023-04-04
```

Columns df_new: ['date', 'Pos_Neg', 'COMAN']

```
date       Pos_Neg    COMAN                          
2021-03-05  0.131192  0.131192
2021-03-18  0.291161  0.291161
2021-03-31 -1.042225 -1.042225
```

I'm not sure why date is twice in COMMODITY ... it's not my code

Comment: There could be a couple of reasons why it is not working. Do you have a snippet of both frames, also column names?
Do both Frames have a column in common?

Comment: Impossible to do anything without examples.

Comment: @OliverKristen I has the date column in common.

Comment: Can you try to add the on='date' option to the merge. pd.merge(COMMODITY, df_new, on='date')
But if some dates are missing in one of the df or format is different there could be some issues with the merge.

Comment: @OliverKristen Then I get this error: ValueError: 'date' is both an index level and a column label, which is ambiguous. I guess someone messed up?

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but can you try:
COMMODITY = COMMODITY.reset_index()
df_new = df_new.reset_index()

merger = pd.merge(COMMODITY, df_new, on='date')

Answer (score 1):

You should do something like this: `pd.merge(COMMODITY, df_new, on="date")`

Edit:
If you have COMMODITY index date you can get rid of it by reseting your index: `COMMODITY.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)` before you join.

Edit2:
Another way to solve it: just do this: `pd.merge(COMMODITY, df_new, left_index=True, right_on="date")`